# convert bootstrap drop down html ul tag to asp:DropDownList

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to change bootstrap ul html code into asp:DropDownlist

the problem is that bootstrap uses nested div with nested classes to align ul as dropdownlist along with html input text field.

I convert the input text to be as asp:TextBox control, but not success to convert ul list into asp:DropDownList control

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" /> 
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container ">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-12">

                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                Dropdown
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <!-- /input-group -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

    </div>



    <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

the following is the changes I tried

- success to change the seach input html button into asp.Button.
- success to change html input text into asp.TextBox control
- but without success to change ul into asp.dropDownList

  ```
              <div class="col-lg-12">

                  <div class="input-group">
                      <div class="input-group-btn">
                          <div class="dropdown">
                              <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                  Choose Model
                              <span class="caret"></span>
                              </button>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                              </ul>


                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <%--<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">--%>
                      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <%--<button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>--%>

                          <asp:LinkButton ID="SubmitBtn"
                              runat="server"
                              CssClass="btn btn-default">
                              <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                          </asp:LinkButton>
                      </span>
                  </div>
                  <!-- /input-group -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.row -->


          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
          </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

      </div>
  ```

the disired output shoud be like the following

how can I have the same bootstrap output with asp:DropDownList ?

[image]

Comment: Don't get confused `asp:DropDownList` that produces html `select` with this requirement. For something of this sort it might require Custom control(s) that will produce the desired output depending from where your `html` starts at and also what inputs it should take... How did you solve the   `asp:TextBox` ?

Comment: @Searching the above code is running in html I am trying to change html tags into asp controls with the same output, so changing html into input text is simple because it is one tag with one class, but replacing ul html tag is difficult because there are muliple tags nested, so how to get the above layout with asp controls?

Answer (score 1):

Well there is no OOB to do that sort of rendering but you can go with this quick/dirty option

Given that you want to start from the `input-group` element the form would be like this

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <asp:Panel ID="inputgroup" class="input-group" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="inputgroupbtn" class="input-group-btn" runat="server">
            <asp:Panel ID="dropdown" class="dropdown" runat="server">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                    Choose Model
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" class="dropdown-menu">
                    <LayoutTemplate>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                        </ul>
                    </LayoutTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="_hyperlink_"
                                NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Url") %>'
                                Text='<%#Eval("Text") %>'
                                runat="server" />
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        <li></li>
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                </asp:ListView>
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <span class="input-group-btn">    
            <asp:LinkButton ID="SubmitBtn"
                runat="server"
                CssClass="btn btn-default">
                        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </asp:LinkButton>
        </span>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

In you code behind for the links (as a sample only)

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<UrlLink> list = new List<UrlLink>();
        list.Add(new UrlLink() { Url = "http://www.google.com", Text = "Google" });
        list.Add(new UrlLink() { Url = "http://stackoverflow.com", Text = "Stackoverflow" });
        ListView1.DataSource = list;
        ListView1.DataBind();
    }
```

//UrlLink class

```
public class UrlLink
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

`ul` element is produced by `asp:ListView`. If you want to do something like `<MyControls:DropDownControl>`, so that you can reuse them, then you will need to write this entire part as a custom control. This tut might be useful [asp.net_custom_controls.htm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net/asp.net_custom_controls.htm) . Hope this helps. Let us know

Comment: Thank you for reply, your answer is good, but did there is no asp.DropdownList, I tried for a long time and I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

At last I figure it out.
it is all about bootstrap classes in asp.net controls.

here is the solution

```
<div class="container ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">

                            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1">Action</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Another Action</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3">Something else here</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        </span>
                        <div class="add-clear-span has-feedback " />
                        <%--<input type="text" name="Search"  required="required" class="" autocomplete="off">--%>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="SearchText" CssClass="form-control suggestIngredient ui-autocomplete-input" placeholder="Search for ..." runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <span class="add-clear-x form-control-feedback glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle" style="color: rgb(204, 204, 204); cursor: pointer; text-decoration: none; overflow: hidden; position: absolute; pointer-events: auto; right: 0px; top: 0px; display: none;"></span>
                    </div>

                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <%--<button class="btn btn-default" type="button"></button>--%>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="SearchBtn" CssClass="btn btn-primary" runat="server"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></asp:LinkButton>
                    </span>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        </div>
```